# using Integration by parts

Tags: calculus, integration

Struggling with trying to figure out which part should be $u$ and $dv$.

$$\int_0^12x^7e^{x^8+1}dx$$

I tried parts method and set $u = e^{x^8+1}$ and $dv= 2x^7$. I end up getting another tricky looking integral for $vdu$. Do I just keep applying the parts method or did I screw up?

Comment: there is an obvious u-substitution, why aren't you using it ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using integration by parts, setting $u=x^8+1$ gives us $x^7dx=(1/8)du$ and $$\int_{0}^{1}2e^{x^8+1}\color{red}{x^7dx}=\int_{1}^{2}2e^u\cdot\color{red}{\frac{du}{8}}$$which should be easy to do with.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The problem is that integration by parts isn't the tool to use here.

Can you see that the multiplier of the exponential is very nearly the derivative of what's in the exponent?

You should be thinking of the fact that
$$\left(e^{f(x)}\right)'=f'(x)e^{f(x)}$$
Except for some multiplicative constant, your integrand is almost in this form.